# How to display Jquery Dialog on blur?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to display some information (in jquery dialog), so when user enters a value in the text box and on blur It should make an ajax call using that value and display information in the dialog box.

This is what i tried so far:

```
 $(function () {
   $('#MyTextbox').blur(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id >= "1") {
        alert(id);
        ShowData();
      }
    });
 });

function ShowData() {
   $("#dialog").dialog();
}
```

Is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: what isn't working? is the alert working?

Comment: alert working. ShowData() function gets called but dialog not displaying. where i have all information under div with id #dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {

   $("#dialog").dialog({ isOpen : false});//Create Dialog


   $('#MyTextbox').blur(function () {
       var id = parseInt($(this).val()); //See correction here


       if(id >= 1) {
         //Get content and append to dialog
         $("#dialog").dialog("open");//Open dialog
       } 
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ajax script in php yo can call it directly from the blur event function and pass html result to the dialog box.

```
$('#MyTextbox').blur(function () {
    // the ajax call
    $.get('ajaxScript.php',{id: $("this").val()}, 
    function(data){
       //the result in html to the dialog 
       $("#dialog").empty().append(data).dialog();
    },'html');
});
```

hope this helps